# is there something wrong with my basic zero initialization code?

Tags: c++, c++17, zero-initialization

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

int x{ 19 };
std::cout << "Hola!" << '\n';
std::cout << "Me llamo Kay\n";
std::cout << "And I am " << x << " years old\n";
std::cout << "Who are you?\n";
int y{};
std::cin >> y;
std::cout << "You are " << y << "?" << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

So i want the code to run a program that goes:

1. Hola!
2. Me llamo Kay
3. And I am 19 years old
4. Who are you?
5. [user enters whatever]
6. You are [user entered]?

But instead what I get is:

1. Hola!
2. Me llamo Kay
3. And I am 19 years old
4. Who are you?
5. [user enters whatever]
6. You are 0?

Edit: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5PpV.png)

Comment: What is "whatever" for example? A number? A float? A text?

Comment: `int y` means `y` holds an integer.  You probably want `std::string y`.

Comment: You have a duplicate definition of y. Please show working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared y as an integer. This means y can only be used to contain a number. In your case, you want a to contain a std::string. This means any kind of text, like the text the user has entered. So simply change `int y{}` into `std::string y;`. And don't forget you can only declare a variable once in c++, so you'll have to remove one of the declarations for y.

Comment: ohhh. I see. Okay! Thanks so much!